How to make sure OnModelCreating is always triggered in my .NET integration test?
I just wrote a integration tests with .NET 8 using WebApplicationFactory for a repository class.  What became clear to me from the logging is that one of the tests is behaving differently when I run it seperately (selecting each test in the runner to run it from there) instead of running it as part of a full run (just telling the runner in resharper to run all tests).
As a consequence, I cannot exactly reproduce the expected behaviour in a full run. I want to fix that.
Here is my Program.cs:

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplicationContextIssue;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options =>
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList")); // Use an in-memory database for simplicity

        builder.Services.AddScoped<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}

Here is my repository class:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplicationContextIssue;

public class TodoRepository : ITodoRepository
{
    private readonly TodoContext _context;

    public TodoRepository(TodoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TodoItem>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TodoItem?> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        await _context.TodoItems.AddAsync(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

Here is my DbContext class:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplicationContextIssue;

public class TodoContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options, ILogger<TodoContext> logger) : base(options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation("TodoContext!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnModelCreating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // You can add configurations here if needed
        modelBuilder.Entity<TodoItem>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}

Here is the test class:
using ConnectingApps.Xunit.TestLogger;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace WebApplicationContextIssue.IntegrationTest;

public class TodoRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public TodoRepositoryTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _factory = new TestLoggerWebApplicationFactory<Program>(output);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("title1")]
    [InlineData("title2")]
    public async Task AddAsync_AddsTodoItemSuccessfully(string title)
    {
        // Arrange
        var todoItem = new TodoItem
        {
            Title = title,
            IsCompleted = false
        };

        // Resolve the repository from the service provider
        using (var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var repository = services.GetRequiredService<ITodoRepository>();

            // Act
            await repository.AddAsync(todoItem);

            // Assert
            var addedItem = await repository.GetByIdAsync(todoItem.Id);
            Assert.NotNull(addedItem);
            Assert.Equal(todoItem.Title, addedItem.Title);
            Assert.Equal(todoItem.IsCompleted, addedItem.IsCompleted);
        }
    }
}

To see the logging in my test output, I use this NuGet Package.
Here are the test outputs when running the rests seperately:
*2024-09-01 11:49:32 [Information] TodoContext!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 11:49:33 [Information] OnModelCreating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 11:49:33 [Information] Saved 1 entities to in-memory store.*
and
*2024-09-01 11:49:37 [Information] TodoContext!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 11:49:38 [Information] OnModelCreating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 11:49:38 [Information] Saved 1 entities to in-memory store.*
This is exactly the output I expect!
However, when running all tests in one run:
*2024-09-01 12:13:57 [Information] TodoContext!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 12:13:58 [Information] OnModelCreating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 12:13:58 [Information] Saved 1 entities to in-memory store.*
and
*2024-09-01 12:13:58 [Information] TodoContext!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-01 12:13:58 [Information] Saved 1 entities to in-memory store.*
So what becomes clear here is that the OnModelCreating is not recalled when running the tests seperately.
A test simply behaves differently when it is running as part of a full run. I want each test to run in the same way no matter if it runs as part of a full run or just runs seperately. Because then I can compare the test results and rely on the tests.
How to achieve this (tests always run in the same way)?

Note: Solving this will be especially useful when the behaviour of OnModelCreating is configurable.


In my opinion, to solve this issue, you could consider creating a new factory instance for each test method.
But it will cause a lot of system resource and actually, I don't understand why you need call onmodelcreating each time.
The codes like this:
public class TodoRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public TodoRepositoryTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("title1")]
    [InlineData("title2")]
    public async Task AddAsync_AddsTodoItemSuccessfully(string title)
    {
        // Create a new factory instance for each test
        var factory = new TestLoggerWebApplicationFactory<Program>(_output);

        // Arrange
        var todoItem = new TodoItem
        {
            Title = title,
            IsCompleted = false
        };

        // Resolve the repository from the service provider
        using (var scope = factory.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var repository = services.GetRequiredService<ITodoRepository>();

            // Act
            await repository.AddAsync(todoItem);

            // Assert
            var addedItem = await repository.GetByIdAsync(todoItem.Id);
            Assert.NotNull(addedItem);
            Assert.Equal(todoItem.Title, addedItem.Title);
            Assert.Equal(todoItem.IsCompleted, addedItem.IsCompleted);
        }
    }
}


This does not solve the problem.

So now, you want to make sure the onmodelcreating is running for all the test once or running it for all method separately ? Since this method is called when the model for a derived context has been initialized, so it will be called multiple time according to your codes.

The logs don't confirm that.  I shared the logs in  post. It should be called for each test. But that just does not happen. The problem does not become clear from the code. It becomes clear from the logs.
